# How to mark my emails as read or seen in php?

Tags: php, email, imap

I am working on my php code to mark my email as read or seen. I understand that there is alot of answers out there, I have did alot of google search and I have tried to use each different codes, but unfortunately it did not work for me. It will not mark my email as read or seen when I tried to use each different codes. It can only mark my emails as Unread or not seen when I use `imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen");`.

Here is what I have already tried so far:

```
imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen");
imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\UnSeen");
imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\UNSEEN");
imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen \\Recent");
```

And I have already tried this:

```
imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen", ST_UID);
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
$mailbox = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$email_number= '236';

$inbox = imap_open($mailbox, $username, $password) or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

if (PEAR::isError($inbox)) {
    echo "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Error:</span> Unable to build a connection.";
}
else
{
    imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen \\Recent");
    echo "mailbox have been marked as read";
}
imap_expunge($inbox);
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

What I expect to do is to mark my emails as read or seen. I have tried everything and I don't know what to do.

Can you please show me an example code how I could mark my emails as read or seen?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765736/set-an-email-as-seen-on-imap-server and, for reference, you might find http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html useful too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set an email as SEEN on IMAP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765736/set-an-email-as-seen-on-imap-server)

Comment: @RamRaider thank you for post the links, I am sorry but I want to set one email as read without set all emails as read at the same time. How I could do that?

Comment: Robert do you want to mark all e-mail or just one e-mail as read?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I want to mark one email as read. How I could do that?

Comment: @Robert Jones, in the link referenced by @RamRaider you have a line `$status = imap_setflag_full($mbox, $mail, "\\Seen \\Flagged", ST_UID);` which is in the loop. Just use it without loop :)

Comment: I have tested and it works. You'll need to use `$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN');
        imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen");
        imap_expunge($inbox);`

Comment: I have tested again and it works fine with `imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen");` as you need to put `$email_number` as your email number to set the email as read :)